# How to GET data from end point using JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, rest, get

There is some data stored at a end point(url).  And the file is a .jsp file.

The following is the data.

```
{"successful":"true","rows":[{"zip":"56431","user_id":"35","name":"test"}]}
```

How can I get the data from this end point? www.test.com/test.jsp

i.e. something like this

```
var data = get("www.test.com/test.jsp"); 
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
```

etc..

Is that possible?

Comment: What is an "end point"?

Comment: Lets just say its a URL to a .jsp file containing the data.

Comment: Is your question how to do this in java or javascript (can't tell based on your tags)

Comment: Javascript would be preferred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.org) makes this simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callEndpoint() {
    $.getJSON('/endpoint.jsp', function(data) {
        $('#output').append(data.rows[0].user_id);
    });
}
callEndpoint();
</script>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks great however for some reason it keeps freezing up in the callEndpoint function.. I have been running this code in phpstorm and trying a number of things such as accessing a local .jsp file as opposed to an external one.. I even tried running an w3shools example locally on my computer and it seemed to freeze after the $.getJSON call. meaning if I put an alert message after it it never gets to it..  Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Comment: It may be silently failing. I recommend using Firebug to step through the code. The `getJSON` function also allows you to access more details around the success or failure of the AJAX request. Look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: For some reason when running the chrome browser via phpStorm it was not working for me.  Ironically I installed FireFox so that I could run Firebug, I was planning on doing some debugging when it worked.. So apparently PHPStorm-Chrome->$.getJson (mac) combo was not working for me.. But firefox did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code can help you,

```
var data = '{"successful":"true","rows":[{"zip":"56431","user_id":"35","name":"test"}]}'
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
var userID = jsonObj.rows[0].user_id;

var name = jsonObj.rows[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);//Were string is your data string
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) answer for more details.

I don't know what you mean by end point, but I hope you aren't parsing the data from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an AJAX solution, you can use this function.  It can send variables through the URL and receive a response from the source url.

```
function get_(url, func)
{
 var http;
 try { http = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { alert(\"Your browser broke!\"); return false; } } }

 http.open(\"GET\", url, true);
 http.onreadystatechange = function() { if(http.readyState == 4) { func(http); } }
 http.send(null);
}
```

To use this, here is an example of how a button triggers the call and specified a response handler function:

HTML

```
<button onClick='get_("source_url.jsp", showResponse);'> Show the response </button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function showResponse(h) { alert(h.responseText); }
```

To be clear, the second parameter of the get_ function is a reference to a function.  Whatever function you specify when using the get_ function, it passes a single parameter which containes the .responseText property, which is the output from the source_url file.

I use this function all the time, though I have another version that works with my PHP server to authenticate the user so that there is no unauthorized loading/saving of information from/to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the input jack, unfortunately I am not familiar with Ajax so I don't know how I would implement the get_ function.. An quick example with the full source would be helpful if its not too much trouble.

Comment: Actually, the code is complete as-is.  The get_ function is a normal javascript function. It's counterpart is the showResponse javascript function. All you need to do is replace "source_url.jsp" with the actual file name that outputs the text you want your page to receive.  For the sake of an example, it could even be a static html file. If it was php, anything that get printed or echoed will be shown in the alert dialog.